# Reading a query string parameter inside an Angular 4 guard?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to read a query string parameter inside the `canActivate` method of an Angular guard. Unfortunately, the `queryParams` parameter from both `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and `RouterStateSnapshot` are empty, even though the query string exists.

Example: bla.com/?uid=123

That query string parameter can be sent to any URL and i want my guard to be able to look at it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Example url:
http://example.com/oper/sale?code=you_code_here

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
...

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    console.log("code", route.queryParams.code);
}
```

Comment: I glanced at your code multiple times and still messed it up. To anyone else: THIS DOESN'T GO IN THE CONSTRUCTOR. It goes in the call to `canActivate` inside your guard. The updated documentation is here: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data and the updated method argument list for `canActivate` is `canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)`. Notice how `next` and `state` are passed in for you!

Answer (score 3):

Or if you are using parameter in your route:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  console.log("Id:", route.params['uid']);
}
```